# How to make a div's title appear when it is behind another div?

Tags: html, css, razor

So I have a 2 divs structure as so:

```
<div class="div-front"></div>
<div class="div-behind1" title="@actualHeight1%" style="height:@actualHeight1%"></div>
<div class="div-behind2" title="@actualHeight2%" style="height:@actualHeight2%"></div>
```

Essentially, I have a div (.div-front) absolutely positioned with a higher z-index so that it stacks properly in front of two other divs (.div-behind1 & 2). This is just how it needs to be structured, so I cannot change how this part is laid out.

.div-behind1 and 2 are basically bar charts that stack on each other, reperesenting different values, and the height increases in percentage to represent the data being loaded in. It also has a title that displays the percentage on hover. However, since these are behind .div-front, the title doesn't show upon hover.

I am unsure of my options to get these titles to display. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is going to be difficult for you because z-index won't help since the titles would be children of the divs behind, thus even if they have a higher z-index than the front-div it won't override it because it respects the parent.  Can you made a fiddle that can be used to experiment?

Comment: Or you could possibly use some jQuery to have the hover actually create the titles in a new div outside of the parent, thus you could apply z-index that would be respected.  Without the code it is tough to tell.

Comment: My only concern with using jQuery is that it doesn't play nicely with imported data a lot of times, and I end up having to set a timeout which can cause problems.

Comment: What is the problem you are actually trying to solve, just to get the percentage to display on hover? I don't see why this would be a problem with JS/jQ

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get it to display the title on hover, but the div in front of the rest is block it. I am playing around with JS/jQ solutions now.

Comment: Any way you can throw it into a fiddle somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only way I can think with CSS only is to create 2 empty divs, and make the `z-index` higher than `div-front` and add the `title` to them.

```
<div class="div-front"></div>

<div class="div-above1" title="@actualHeight1%"></div>
<div class="div-above2" title="@ actualHeight2%"></div>

<div class="div-behind1" title="@actualHeight1%" style="height:@actualHeight1%"></div>
<div class="div-behind2" title="@actualHeight2%" style="height:@actualHeight2%"></div>
```

And the CSS is like.

```
.div-above1 {
    height: /*tall enough to cover the chart*/
    width: /*same as the div-behind1 */
    z-index: /*higher than div-front*/
}
```

Do the similar thing for the other one.

Comment: This might be crazy enough to work. I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Just tested this...it would work perfectly if there was only one bar chart, but since there are mutliple that stack on top of eachother, its only displaying one of the titles on hover.

Comment: Well it wasn't the solution I ended up using since it didn't work in my situation but I might as well give points to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gotta use javascript functions and css together to realize it.
Add moveOn function and MoveOut functions to cover Div, in the moveOn function, get title1 and title2. Create new variables in cover div and set float positions to show the titles.

Below is part of the code, I did not finish them all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myFunction(e) {

        var title1 = document.getElementById("div-behind1");
        var title2 = document.getElementById("div-behind2");

        //add code to locate where you want to show the titles.
        //probably you need to create a new element like <span></span> with float and transpant preoperties in the cover div for showing titles. Set appropriate relative positions of two <span></span> is needed.

    }

    function clear(e) {
        //clear the titles.
        //simply empty the <span>
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div onmousemove="myFunction(event)" onmouseout="clear()" class="div-front">abc <span id="s1"> </span></div>
    <div id="div-behind1" title="@actualHeight1%" style="height:@actualHeight1%">e</div>
    <div id="div-behind2" title="@actualHeight2%" style="height:@actualHeight2%">t</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try the CSS only suggestion from user sdcr, but if that doesn't work, I will try this.

Comment: Good luck with that. I would like to see how you experience with user scdr, never used it before.